# Finding out how many programs I have not installed from a list with grep/awk in archlinux

Tags: linux, grep, awk, pacman

I want to see how many packages from a list are not installed. I use archlinux, so I use pacman -Q to determine if a package is installed. If it is not installed, it returns a message like: "error: package 'package-name' was not found".

I thought I could use `grep -c 'error'` like this:

```
pacman -Q autoconf automake binutils bison fakeroot flex gcc libtool m4 make patch pkg-config | grep -c 'error'
```

But for me it returns:

> error: package 'bison' was not found
>   error: package 'pkg-config' was not found
>   0

It returns 0, but I would like it to return 2. Even with awk it doesn't work:

```
pacman -Q autoconf automake binutils bison fakeroot flex gcc libtool m4 make patch pkg-config | awk '/error: / {count++} END {print count}'
```

For me, this returns:

> error: package 'bison' was not found
>   error: package 'pkg-config' was not found

So my guess is that variable `count` doesn't even have a value since it doesn't get printed. I also tried `wc -l`, but that doesn't work, it just returns 0 for me.

What is the correct way to print the number of not-installed packages?

EDIT: I noticed when I do:

```
pacman -Q autoconf automake binutils bison fakeroot flex gcc libtool m4 make patch pkg-config > tempfile  
cat tempfile
```

The two rows containing the error message are not added to `tempfile` (the rest of the command output does). Thought this might help solving this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the error messages are not send to `STDOUT` but `STDERR`. You have to explicitly redirect `STDERR` as well, e.g:

```
pacman -Q bison patch pkg-config 2>&1 | grep -c 'error'
```

If you have something like bash or zsh you can use `|&` to automatically redirect `STDOUT` as well as `STDERR`:

```
pacman -Q bison patch pkg-config |& grep -c 'error'
```

Comment: Ofcourse, the message even has the word "error" in it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The errors are printed to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Your pipe (`|`) only sees the `stdout` output.  You can redirect `stderr` to `stdout` before the pipe, and then all of your output will go through `grep`:

`pacman -Q autoconf automake binutils bison fakeroot flex gcc libtool m4 make patch pkg-config 2>&1 | grep -c 'error'`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `wc -l` to count the number of lines outputted.

So if `pacman -Q autoconf automake binutils bison fakeroot flex gcc libtool m4 make patch pkg-config | grep -c 'error'` is outputting:

```
error: package 'bison' was not found
error: package 'pkg-config' was not found
```

you can run `pacman -Q autoconf automake binutils bison fakeroot flex gcc libtool m4 make patch pkg-config | grep -c 'error' | wc -l` to count the number of times grep outputted a line.

Comment: I thought the same, but that doesn't work for me. Your last comments returns "1" for me, I think that is because it counts the last row (which has the 0 from the grep -c command). If I remove the -c from grep and pipe it to `wc -l` it still returns 0.